# Координаты мыши внутри div не зависимо от окна браузера

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как можно узнать координаты курсора мыши, относительно div, а вернее внутри него?
  Потому что если использовать `clientX/clientY` или `pageX/pageY`, то стоит изменить размер окна браузера и будут другие значения, соответственно, функционал работать не будет.
 Или же у другого человека расширение монитора больше и все, функционал не работает.

Answer (score 3):

Узнать координаты блока, из pageX вычесть их - получится относительно блока.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.coor-demo');
let divRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log( JSON.stringify( divRect ) );

div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  let relX = e.pageX - divRect.left;
  let relY = e.pageY - divRect.top;
  
  this.textContent = `
    relX: ${ relX }, absX: ${ e.pageX }
    relY: ${ relY }, absY: ${ e.pageY }
  `;
});

/* Перезапись координатов блока при изменении размеров окна */
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  divRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
});
```

```css
.coor-demo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="coor-demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам не нужно поддерживать совсем старые браузеры, то можно использовать свойства `offsetX` и `offsetY` события передвижения мыши.

[Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=offsetX)

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.coor-demo');

div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

  this.textContent = `
    relX: ${ e.offsetX }, absX: ${ e.pageX }
    relY: ${ e.offsetY }, absY: ${ e.pageY }
  `;
});
```

```css
.coor-demo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="coor-demo"></div>
```